# Add same ID into 2 different tables

Tags: php, mysql

When i add a new from my custom CMS, i need to add some diferent info about this post at 2 different tables.

So the first table is DATA and the Second  is SEO.

When I press on PUBLISH button at my cms , i add some data at DATA table  with xx id, also i add some data at SEO table , but i need that the data inserted at SEO table have same ID with the data added at DATA table.

I have looked around but i haven't found what i wanted.

Please if some one know how to do that,please answer to this post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's tricky without any more information but I'd guess you're looking for [`mysql_insert_id()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php)

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO table (col) VALUES (1)';
mysql_query($sql);

$inserted_id = mysql_insert_id();

// Run your next query
```

Comment: remember to set AUTO_INCREMENT attribute on DATA.id

Answer (score 1):

assuming you are using msysql and the first table has autoincrement id, then you can use

```
$id = mysql_insert_id()
```

to get the id after the first insert, then use that id in the 2nd insert